# Deploying Metadata through Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment fails with a null message

Tags: apex, api, custom-metadata, summer-17

I am trying to play with the new Summer'17 feature of **Deploying and Retrieving Metadata through Apex**. I was trying to use the method `Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment` to update existing custom metadata values in the org. Here is how my Custom Metadata looks like -[image]

These are the values present in the Custom Metadata -[image]

Below is the code snippet, where I am trying to update the value (Enabled checkbox to false) for Process Builder Preference.

```
Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
customMetadata.fullName = 'Admin_Preference__mdt.Process_Builder_Preference';

Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
customField.field = 'Enabled__c';
customField.value = Boolean.valueOf('false');
customMetadata.values.add(customField);

Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);

MyDeployCallback callback = new MyDeployCallback();

// Enqueue custom metadata deployment
Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
```

Here is the `MyDeployCallback` class -

```
public class MyDeployCallback implements Metadata.DeployCallback {
    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result,
                             Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded) {
            System.Debug('--++-- Deployment is successful');
        } else {
           System.Debug('--++-- Deployment failed with status: ' + result.status + ' with error message: ' + result.errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

From log what I am getting is: -

> 11:43:17.8 (9856354)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|--++-- Deployment failed with status: Failed with error message: null

Any idea what wrong is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There can be several reason of this deployment error. Possible reason is mandatory field is missed or the referenced metadata name is incorrect. Below is the working code to **create** and **update** Custom Metadata via `Metadata` namespace.

**Callback class:-**

```
public class CustomMetadataCallback implements Metadata.DeployCallback {
    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result,
                             Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded) {
            System.debug(' ===>'+ result);
        } else {
            // Deployment was not successful
            System.debug(' ===> fail '+ result);
        }
    }
}
```

**Metadata Creation Script:-**

```
    // Set up custom metadata to be created in the subscriber org.
    Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
    customMetadata.fullName = 'Response_Type.NotFound_Code';
    customMetadata.label = 'NotFound_Code';

    Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
    customField.field = 'Status_Code__c';
    customField.value = '404';

    customMetadata.values.add(customField);

    Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
    mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);

    // Setup deploy callback, MyDeployCallback implements
    // the Metadata.DeployCallback interface (code for
    // this class not shown in this example)
    CustomMetadataCallback callback = new CustomMetadataCallback();

    // Enqueue custom metadata deployment
    Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
```

**Detail:-**
1. Metdata Name is `Response_Type__c` it has a field called `Status_Code__c`
2. Above we are trying to add new Record to response named "Not Found".

**Things missed in question's code:-**
1. Metadata name does not require `__mdt`.
2. MasterLabel field is not mentioned.

Comment: Awesome Ashwani. It is working now. The problem is with label field missing. fullName can have _mdt and it is working fine.